# Match value with range value in column

Tags: sql, django

I am having table with column registration year with values like '2017-2019' and '2014-2016.

If my input value is 2018 then what will be my SQL query to get that record which is in between '2017-2019'.

| id | registration_year |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2014-2016 |
| 2 | 2017-2019 |

above is DB table and my input is 2018. Then it should return id 2.

What will be my sql query.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please review [ask] and then update the post with the table DDL and examples of queries you have already tried. Please tag with only one database. Are you using MySQL or PostgreSQL?

Comment: There isn't an efficient way to query the data with the current structure. Consider replacing the text column with integer values for start and end year stored as either discrete columns or as a single range column. With the current text column, you could extract the year fields with string functions, e.g., (for PostgreSQL) either `split_part` or `split_to_array`, cast the extracted values to integers, and then perform integer comparisons. As I said, while this approach will work, it is not efficient.

Answer (score 5):

Honestly now would be a good time to change your table design.  Consider this version, which stores the registration start and end years in different columns:

```
id | registration_start | registration_end
1  | 2014               | 2016
2  | 2017               | 2019
```

With this properly designed table in place, now you only need a simple range comparison:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE registration_start <= 2018 AND registration_end >= 2018;
```

Comment: Yes, this design will be much better here. I think it's more readable to write ...WHERE 2018 BETWEEN registration_start AND registration_end. Of course, it's kind of taste, I just wanted to mention this option.

Answer (score 1):

```
... WHERE @input_value BETWEEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(column, '-', 1) AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(column, '-', -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with TB's answer where you should redesign your table structure. Here's a solution with the current structure.

```
select id
from my_table 
where left(registration_year, 4)::integer <= 2018
  and right(registration_year, 4)::integer >= 2018;
```

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the record that matches the input year (2018) with the registration year ranges in the SQL table, you can use the following SQL query with the `BETWEEN` operator:

```
SELECT 
  id, registration_year 
FROM your_table_name 
  WHERE 
    2018 BETWEEN 
      SUBSTRING(registration_year, 1, 4) AND
      SUBSTRING(registration_year, 6, 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you always, or almost always, start and end together then rather than a string define the column as a [integer range](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-BUILTIN). This still results in a single column. Then query with the [range containment operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html) (**<@**). So: (See demo)

```
create table my_table( id   integer  generated always as identity
                                     primary key 
                     , registration int4range
                     );
select * 
  from my_table 
 where <input_year> <@ registration;
```

A note on demo result. When queried the `registration` column will appear as `[2017,2020)`. This is correct for your data values (row 2). That is because when queried Postgres always responds as *contains the lower bound but does not contain the upper bound*. However you will notice that row was created as *contains lower bound and contains upper bound*.

Answer (score 0):

It is always better to keep your Database Normalized. The very basic Normalization step is to have "atomic" columns (Each column should have as precise and single information as possible).

It is better to alter the design of your database and have separate columns for "start_date" and "end_date".

```
id || start_year || end_year
```

This will make querying your database a lot easier.

With the current design, you can use the following query to get the desired output:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name 
WHERE
SUBSTRING(registeration_year,1,4) <= 2018 
AND 
SUBSTRING(registeration_year,6,4) >= 2018
```

All in all the best solution would be to change your database design as soon as possible.